# How to write "0" rounded to two decimal places??

Tags: education

I'm working on some function that rounds a number to specific decimal places, and I want to ask; what if we have an output that has decimal places less than required. 
e.g. "$1.002$" rounded to two decimal places, will be "$1$" or "$1.00$"
and also "$0$" (zero) rounded to two decimal places, will be "$0$" or "$0.00$".
thanks :)

Comment: 1.00 and 0.00..

Comment: @Haytham Mahmoud If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the following rule is adopted:

consider: $N=1.00abcd...$

set: $X=(N-1)1000=a.bcd...$

$N$ rounded to two decimal places is

- 1.00 if $0\leq X <5$
- 1.01 if $X\geq5$

**EG**

$$1.006347 \to 1.01$$
$$1.005012 \to 1.01$$
$$1.004912 \to 1.00$$